# Finding probabilities given a distribution function

Tags: probability

Let

$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{4} \chi_{[0, \infty)}(x) + \frac{1}{2} \chi_{[1, \infty)}(x) + \frac{1}{4}\chi_{[2, \infty) } (x) $$

Suppose the probablity $P$ is given by $P( ( -\infty, x]) = F(x) $. I am trying to find $P( ( - \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} ))$, $P( ( -\frac{1}{2} ,\frac{3}{2}) $ and $P( [0,2))$.

#### Attempt:

$P( ( -1/2,1/2)) = F( 1/2^-) - F( - 1/2) = \lim_{x \to 1/2^-} F(x) - F( -1/2) = 1/4 -0 = 1/4 $

$P( ( -\frac{1}{2} ,\frac{3}{2}) = F( \frac{3}{2}^-) - F(- \frac{1}{2} ) = 1$

$ P( [0,2)) = F(2^-) - F(0^-) = \lim_{x \to 2^-} F(x) - \lim_{x \to 0^-} F(x) = 1 - 1/4 = 3/4 $

Is this correct? thanks

Comment: F(3/2) = 3/4 and F(0-) = 0

Comment: I find it easiest to plot $F$ and solve the problem visually. You have $P = {1 \over 4} \delta_0 + {1 \over 2} \delta_1 + {1 \over 4} \delta_2$.